# sqlalchemy mysql can we pass multiple hosts?

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, mysql-connector

As per [sqlalchemy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/postgresql.html#specifying-multiple-fallback-hosts) website and [github](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/4392) in postgresql we can pass multiple host when we create database connection:
Ex: `"postgresql+psycopg2://user:pass@/test?host=host1:port1&host=host2:port2&host=host3:port3"`

can we pass multiple hosts in mysql also?